# create Github repository GREY button

Tags: github, repository, github-actions

Create github repository button is greyed out. I tried these steps;

- Created a new token (but not used it)
- tried "add .gitignore" and changed the template from none => java
- changed appearance from dark to light
- signed in and out
  -used a different browser( original chrome => firefox)
- tried using both public & private

So how can I create a repository on github so that I can push my existing project from Ecilipse to Github?

Comment: do you have the  dark reader extension ? There is an error in the repository name or the owner ?

Comment: No I don't have a dark reader extension. I'll add this! There isn't an error in the repo name or the owner.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a hint when you hover the button? Might you have hit some limit? Is there any hint when you go to settings? If none of these help, please share a screenshot.

Comment: No there isnt' any hint. I even tried to do premium but it doesn't work. Nothing when I hoover over the button.